# How to make kivy only click on the top widget

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make it so clicking on this widget doesn't click on the widget behind it while making it possible to still be able to click on the child widgets of that parent widget. Anytime I add something to terminate the event when it is clicked on it won't register clicks on the "content" widget's children. If I don't have that then it clicks on everything my mouse is over whether it's covered or not. This is the code for the resizable subwindows i made:

```
class SubWindow(Widget):
tPosRel = ListProperty()
bColor = ListProperty()
innerColor = ListProperty()
buttonPos = ListProperty()
innerPos = ListProperty()
innerSize = ListProperty()

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.innerPos = (self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 40)
    self.innerSize = (90, 265)
    self.innerColor = (.2, .2, .2, 1)
    self.bColor = (0, 0, 0, 1)
    brightnessAvg = (self.bColor[0] + self.bColor[1] + self.bColor[2])/3.0
    if brightnessAvg > .5:
        self.innerColor = (kwargs["bColor"][0] - .2, kwargs["bColor"][1] - .2, kwargs["bColor"][2] - .2, 1)
    else:
        self.innerColor = (kwargs["bColor"][0] + .2, kwargs["bColor"][1] + .2, kwargs["bColor"][2] + .2, 1)
    #print(self.innerColor)
    self.buttonPos = (self.size[0] - 30, self.size[1] - 30)
    #print(self.pos)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.innerPos = (self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 5)
    #print(self.pos)
    #print(self.bColor)
    #print(self.size)
    self.buttonPos = (self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 25, self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 25)

def on_pos(self, *args):
    self.innerPos = (self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 5)
    self.buttonPos = (self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 25, self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 25)
    if self.ready:
        for x in self.ids["content"].children:
            x.pos = self.ids["content"].pos
    #print(self.innerColor)

def on_size(self, *args):
    self.innerSize = (self.size[0] - 10, self.size[1] - 45)
    self.buttonPos = (self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 25, self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 25)

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        return super(SubWindow, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    # print(self.size)
    # print("Mouse X: " + str(touch.x))
    # print("Mouse Y: " + str(touch.y))
    if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 30 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[
        1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] + 5:
        self.side = 'up'
        print("up hit detect...")
        self.yInit = self.pos[1]
        self.hInit = self.size[1]
        # self.tPosRel = touch - self.pos
        touch.grab(self)
        return True

    if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[
        1] + 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 21:
        self.side = 'right'
        print("right hit detect...")
        self.xInit = self.pos[0]
        self.wInit = self.size[0]
        touch.grab(self)
        return True

    if touch.x > self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.y > self.pos[
        1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
        self.side = 'down'
        print("down hit detect...")
        self.yInit = self.pos[1]
        self.hInit = self.size[1]
        touch.grab(self)
        return True

    if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + 5 and touch.y < self.pos[
        1] + self.size[1]:
        self.side = 'left'
        print("left hit detect...")
        #print(self.size)
        self.xInit = self.pos[0]
        self.wInit = self.size[0]
        touch.grab(self)
        return True

    if touch.x > self.pos[0] and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 30 and touch.y > self.pos[1] + self.size[
        1] - 22 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + self.size[1] - 5:
        print("top hit detect...")
        self.side = 'window'
        self.tPosRel = (touch.x - self.pos[0], touch.y - self.pos[1])
        touch.grab(self)
        return True

    if touch.x > self.pos[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[
        1] + 5:
        self.side = 'leftcorner'
        print("left hit detect...")
        #print(self.size)
        self.xInit = self.pos[0]
        self.wInit = self.size[0]
        self.yInit = self.pos[1]
        self.hInit = self.size[1]
        touch.grab(self)
        return True

    if touch.x > self.pos[0] + self.size[0] - 5 and touch.x < self.pos[0] + self.size[0] + 5 and touch.y > self.pos[
        1] - 5 and touch.y < self.pos[1] + 5:
        self.side = 'rightcorner'
        print("right hit detect...")
        #print(self.size)
        self.xInit = self.pos[0]
        self.wInit = self.size[0]
        self.yInit = self.pos[1]
        self.hInit = self.size[1]
        touch.grab(self)
        return True
    return super(SubWindow, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Kv lang code:

```
<SubWindow>:
size_hint: (None, None)
FloatLayout:
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    size_hint: (None, None)
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.bColor
        Rectangle:
            size: root.size
            pos: root.pos
    Button:
        size: 20, 20
        pos: root.buttonPos
        size_hint: (None, None)
        text: "X"
        on_release: root.close(root)
    FloatLayout:
        pos: root.innerPos
        size: root.innerSize
        size_hint:(None, None)
        id: content
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: root.innerColor
            Rectangle:
                pos: content.pos
                size: root.innerSize
```

Answer (score 0):

So i added a block of code at the end of that. I made it so it only dispatches the on_touch_down event to the subwindow's children.

```
    if self.ids["content"].collide_point(*touch.pos):
        for x in self.ids["content"].walk():
            x.on_touch_down(touch)
        return True
```